# iPhone iOS5 iCloud do both apps have to be open to receive each other's iCloud updates?

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-data, icloud

I'm testing a library-based iPhone app with iCloud enabled. With such app, changes to the core data persistent store are propagated across multiple devices.

What interests me is: **Do iCloud "documents and data" changes are propagated across devices when the app that needs to be updated is closed?**
Scenario: Device A makes changes, Device B's app is closed. Once the user restarts device B some time later, the changes are already present.

**or**

**Does the app have to be open on additional devices to request data model updates?** 
Scenario: Device A makes changes to iCloud based core data stack. Device B's app comes online, checks if there are changes, requests changes to be downloaded.

Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former option is closer to the reality, but neither of your options describes the situation correctly.

The point is, if you use CoreData with the iCloud, the update will come whenever

1. your app is running
2. and the OS decides it's the right time to tell the app.

Your app then passively respond to what the OS tells you, as in any event-driven app development. Read [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/_index.html) and/or related WWDC slides available again on Apple's developer website.

Also, Drew McCormack has a series of great blog posts on this topic, called "Under the sheets with iCloud and CoreData", starting [here](http://mentalfaculty.tumblr.com/post/23231176783/under-the-sheets-with-icloud-and-core-data-how-it).